# Output formatting in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to print some integer values in Hex. For this purpose I normally use format() function. Suppose I want to print X in place of 0 in the output will format() help me to do that?

```
>>> format(16,"04X")
'0010'
```

what i need :

```
'XX10'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec), you'll see that the `0` you're using is a special case:

> Preceding the *width* field by a zero (`'0'`) character enables sign-aware zero-padding for numeric types. This is equivalent to a *fill* character of `'0'` with an *alignment type* of `'='`.

That should give you the clue you need to do the same thing with a different fill character. But just in case, let's look at what it says for those *align* and *fill* fields:

> If a valid *align* value is specified, it can be preceded by a *fill* character that can be any character and defaults to a space if omitted.

The syntax for the format string is:

```
format_spec ::=  [[fill]align][sign][#][0][width][,][.precision][type]
```

So, that tells you where to put the *fill* and *align* values:

```
format(16, "X=4X")
```